# Hot to position an image on top of the last tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift

Hot to position an image on top of the last tab bar item,
so it will be ok for different iPhones/iPads screen sizes ?

[image]

Comment: In the image asset catalog, you can define multiple images for different devices. Here you could add a different sized icon for iPad for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIDevice` to check the device that user using.

```
var isIPad: Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.model.hasPrefix("iPad")
}
```

and then depends on the result set your icon.